# How to fix Delphi 2009 Data Explorer?

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-2009

Probably I have messed several delphi versions installations by installing / uninstalling several times (I think I did not follow the order of release). I want to try out Developer Studio 2009 but after installation (althought everything other seems to work fine), when I click The Data Explorer tab nothing is shown on the list. This issue is possibly caused by multiple dbexpress configurations in the registry, but I could not fix it. I get the notion that the uninstaller is of the un-unistaller kind. Registry sucks anyway.

NOTE: OPSYS reinstallation is not an acceptable solution, obviously.

Comment: You probably dont have enough detail to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of why I now develop in a virtual machine.  I can always revert to an earlier snapshot if things get corrupted.

Comment: Actually I have several VMware appliances for different development practices (web, desktop, cross platform). But I did not foresee a product with a hefty price would not mess things up this much. So I broke my own rule :(