# Installing Rad Studio 2007 and Rad Studio 2010 in same machine

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-2007

I want to install Rad Studio 2010 on a machine that already has installed Rad Studio 2007,
There is some compatibility problem?

thanks in advance, Bye.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this answer from Nick Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139844/can-delphi-2009-be-installed-on-the-same-machine-as-delphi-2006-or-delphi-2007/147553#147553).

There is no problem with installing a newer version of Delphi/RAD Studio on a machine that has an older version.  As Mason says, the reverse is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to install an older version of Delphi when a newer version already exists can cause problems.  If you have to have both, either put 2007 in a VM or uninstall 2010 and then install the two Delphis in order, which will work just fine.

Comment: Is there some corollary, i.e. "never commit after midnight"?  Does that apply to VCS, relationships, or both?  ;-)