# FireDAC conflicts with multiple Delphi versions on the same machine

Tags: delphi, firedac

I know that generally it has always been possible to do a [side-by-side installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697916/multiple-delphi-versions-on-the-same-machine) of multiple Delphi versions on a single computer. I have often done that ever since Delphi 1.

However, after installing Delphi XE7 on a computer that had XE6 installed, I get stange errors (e.g. AV's) when trying to use FireDAC or FDExplorer from XE7. At first sight everything is OK, but when trying to connect to a database, the connection "hangs", or you get an AV.

Everything works like normal from XE6.

The installation of XE7 was done using default settings, and XE6 was installed including all updates already prior to installing XE7.

Any advice?

Comment: I haven't experienced this behaviour myself, here both versions work fine.  Have you already tried a full uninstall and reinstall of XE7?  Also check your library path in the IDE, does it point to the right version?

Comment: @Copilot: Everything looks like it should (library paths etc.), and a full uninstall / reinstall of XE7 doesn't change anything. I think I am going to do a final uninstall of XE7 and a repair of XE6 to be sure that XE6 works, and then install XE7 on a new virtual machine.
I am already using virtual machines for the installations. I simply hoped to skip the process of a complete install of all my development tools (in addition to Delphi) from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I did experience same problem myself when first having installed XE7 and defined some connections to Oracle and then installed Delphi XE3 in order to do some stepwise upgrades of third-party components. 
Since I also needed FireDAC I installed the Firedac add-on to XE3, but when I installed the FireDAC add-on to XE3, I lost the connection definitions and when trying to define new connections I got error message that the FDconnectionDefs.Ini was not writeable in the directory (in program files(x86) Delphi/FireDAC_XE3 area.

After checking it turned out that the installer had overwritten the registrations in \HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\FireDAC key.

Turns out the same parameters in that key is reused.

So conclusion is, don't install FireDAC in elder versions, uncheck that option when installing XE4-XE6.

(I have sent a suggestion to Dmitry Arefiev that the FireDAC key should have defined new subkeys, one for each Delphi/C++ version so several installations could be used in parallell as before.

Now that is broken :-(

To clean up, find your correct FDConnectionDefs.ini and change necessary keys.
It may also be possible that the software also has been overwritten.
I did a repair on the latest version of XE7, and after some merging of FDconnectionDefs.ini files I finally got it working