# Possible to reinstall Delphi 2007 without having to reinstall Delphi 2009 too?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2007

I have Delphi 2007 and 2009 installed on the same computer.

I notice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139844/can-delphi-2009-be-installed-on-the-same-machine-as-delphi-2006-or-delphi-2007) that all installations should be installed from oldest to newest.

Does that mean that I'll have to uninstall D2009 and D2007, then reinstall both?  Or can I just uninstall/reinstall D2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had no problem installing Delphi 2007 on a system that already had an up-to-date Delphi 2009 with all its latest updates. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

It means that it best works if installed in order. Otherwise you will just have to wait and see for yourself if it works.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it will probably work to install D2007 after D2009.

If you do run into problems, you won't need to uninstall D2009, simply reinstall over the top and it will correct any corrupted settings.